# WebView.Navigate only shows white screen

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

WebView.Navigate(URI) doesn't load the html file my uri points to. 
PathToIndex is from `StorageFile.Path`.

```
private static readonly Uri HomeUri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///" + PathToIndex, UriKind.Absolute);
```

The html I want to load is from a Zip File I've unpacked before. 
Any suggestions?

EDIT to Jogy's answer:
Here is where i unpacked the zip file:

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var unpackFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(appName+"unzip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

then i save the index.html Path with `StorageFile.Path`.
I tried ms-appdata, but I get `value does not fall within the expected range` exception
I can iterate through all Files with

```
var files = await unpackFolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach(var file in files)
{
   string name = file.Path;
}
```

**with NavigateToString i can see the Html File too, but javascript and css still doesn't work.**

Comment: Where have you unpacked the zip file? If it is in the application data folder, have you tried using "ms-appdata:///local/" as a start of the uri?

Comment: Value of the StorageFile.Path variable is `C:/Data/Users/DefApps/APPDATA/Local/Packages/cd0b1e93-4db9-4f31-ae6a-6d606d6b9e71_n2dsc9ch8qzm0/LocalState/JavaBridgeTestunzip/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ms-appx-web won't work, as it can be used only to load resources from the application package.

I tried ms-appdata and then searched the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) and turns out that:

> WebView does not support the ms-appdata scheme, although it does
>   support the ms-appx-web scheme, which you can use to load content
>   files from your app package.

A workaround would be to read the file contents in a string and then use WebView.NavigateToString().
You can also explore NavigateToLocalStreamUri() if you have external resources for the html.

Comment: yes i already tried the NavigateToLocalStreamUri() method but I dont get the IUriToStreamResolver and I couldn't find any help. Probably have to google a bit to make it work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

To clarify NeoSvet's answer: `ms-appdata` only works if you store your html file in LocalFolder's subfolder, but not in the root, like this: `"ms-appdata:///local/[subfolder_name]/index.html"`.

Reasons for this are described in details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8be0c6c9-0347-4576-835d-6693e495dfbb/webview-bug-load-html-file-from-local-folder-root?forum=w81prevwCsharp), in short: it's done to provide some level of isolation for web content and so that WebView doesn't accidentally expose other content in your local folder.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you...
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7/

My example:

```
StorageFolder d = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile f = await d.CreateFileAsync("index.html", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
Stream str = await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(str))
{
  sw.Write("<html>...</html>");
}
string url = "ms-appdata:///local/folder/index.html";
webView1.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```